# Using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I just started using Entity Framework and it created a Context class which I can use to get all the data i need from it. But I am facing an issue on how I should organize my code, by watching the demos, the person just uses the framework and codes everything on a console application. What is the best way to use Entity Framework and that it looks clean?, what I mean by this is...right now using aspx pages, I could just use the aspx.cs to get the data or save the data. But I do not want this, I would like it to be more organized although the Entity Framework did almost everything by creating the objects etc.. but still, I need to use things like

```
using(var myobject = new MyContextData())
{
    blah blah..
}
```

would you say that it would be nicer to write classes that would wrap these calls?. I would really appreciate any inputs as it would really make me a better programmer using the entity framework.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

I think that Generic Repository is Anti Pattern. But I do not understand @TomTom comment.

**Original Answer:**

As Radim Köhler mentioned you need to implement `Repository and Unit of Work patterns`
But the article he provided in my opinion is not fully correct.

At my current job I use following implementation of these patterns.
For example, we have three types of entities: `Person, Good and Order`. I created repository for Persons. In common case Repository must not be generic. It must contain methods which represent specific queries for this entity. So by looking at the interface of repository you can tell what kinds of queries executed for entity (Person, e.g.). As you will see I created DTO for Person called `PersonWrap`. For creating PersonWrap from Person and updating Person from PersonWrap you can use AutoMapper instead of `PersonWrap()` constructor and `Update()` method. Because EntityFramework `DbContext` implements `Unit of Work` pattern, you just need to provide created DbContext to repository methods. If repository method is a separate action and you do not need DbContext outside of this method you can create and dispose it inside this method.

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
}

public class Good {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Good Good { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Person> Persons { get { return Set<Person>(); }}
    public IDbSet<Good> Goods { get { return Set<Good>(); }}
    public IDbSet<Order> Orders { get { return Set<Order>(); }} 
}

public class PersonRepository {
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll() {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
            return context.Persons.ToList();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetLastWeekPersons() {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
            return context.Persons.Where(p => p.RegistrationDate > new DateTime().AddDays(-7)).ToList();
        }
    } 

    public Person GetById(int id, MyDbContext context) {
        return context.Persons.Include(p => p.Orders).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }

    public Person GetById(int id) {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
            return GetById(id, context);
        }
    }
}

public class PersonWrap {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }

    public PersonWrap(Person person) {
        Id = person.Id;
        FirstName = person.FirstName;
        SecondName = person.SecondName;
        OrderCount = person.Orders.Count;
    }

    public void Update(Person person) {
        person.FirstName = FirstName;
        person.SecondName = SecondName;
    }
}

public class PersonDetailsViewController {
    public PersonWrap Person { get; protected set; }

    public PersonDetailsViewController(int personId) {
        var person = new PersonRepository().GetById(personId);
        if (person != null) {
            Person = new PersonWrap(person);
        }
    }

    public void Save() {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
            var person = new PersonRepository().GetById(Person.Id, context);
            Person.Update(person);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TomTom I had a lot of fun learning about Repository pattern. And top results from Google give following links http://goo.gl/rQ3cO http://goo.gl/Usqkn http://goo.gl/YtyHg It might be more useful if you point out what is my example is anti pattern, because I simplified many things to make it clear.

Comment: @TomTom - Repository is not an anti-pattern.  There is a small contingent of people that suggest not using it with an ORM, but there are stilly plenty of valid uses for it.

Comment: @TomTom Could you give me a link to not stupid repository implementation? Or may be you give me your own alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

This question should everyone, who provides some tutorial about EF, ask. It is hard to say what is the best way, but put all code in the codebehind classes (aspx.cs) does not help extensibility and testability. Please, try to read this article:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Not only it is *official* tutorial on asp.net, but it mostly shows, that Framework EF could be used correctly in currently fancy `Repository pattern`

Comment: +1 for you.and you can go one steep further  and take advantage of using IoC container like AutoFact to completely remove tightly coupling from different layer of your application.

Comment: @Behnam those are my words! ;) In fact, I am mostly using different *ORM* mostly and `StructuraMap` as *IoC container*. But the key point is to use these Architectural/Design patterns and be ready to later interchange their implementation. So I do agree with your extension, thanks

Comment: yes!!i am big fan of two opensource projects in asp.net mvc very extensible framework(e.g: NopCommerce & Orchard).these two frameworks show these patterns in action.i spend a lot of time studying these two great frameworks.

Comment: Ah, Repository is classified AntiPattern ;) At least in the usual implementations.

Comment: Repository is not "classified" as an AntiPattern.  Typically, Anti-patterns have the consensus of the development community.  While there is some disagreement about using repository (particularly from Ayende) his argument relates to using a repository with an ORM with Linq, because you can't effectivly mock a repository and get the same results.  What the anti-repository crowd has failed to do, however, is come up with a decent alternative.  They merely suggest integration testing.

Comment: Seems @TomTom is having allergy to Repository. I think that it's more question of developer skills how you will implement Repository.

Comment: @MystereMan Repository is not an anti pattern much like Singleton is not one - there are tons of people that follow old knowlege and never learn, and insist repiository is apattern, and then there are those who read all the stuff about how repository is bad and should be used very speifically. it is clear you do not like reading up on what makes it an anti pattern. Well, that is YOUR problem - it should not be the problem of the poor soul getting bad advice from you.

Comment: @TomTom I would say, that I do understand what you mean. But most likely we both (all) agree, that any pattern like repository, `DAO`... is better than *code behind* ala aspx.cs, right? ;)

Comment: @TomTom - You have read a few blogs that talked badly about Repository (primarily Ayende, or based on Ayende) and are parroting it.  I am very clear on Ayendes reasons, and he has some valid points.. BUT, his points are *ONLY* relevant to the use of Repository with an ORM.  And, more importantly, he has not suggested a viable alternative for testing.  In fact, when asked directly about testing, he avoids answering.  The best he's come up with is to use integration testing, and that's just not acceptable.  There is no consensus on this issue, unlike Singleton.  So please don't say I am ignorant

Comment: @TomTom - By the way, it's really only the GENERIC repository that some people have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track for creating classes to handle your EF.

The biggest benefit for doing it this way is able to unit test easily.

Test early and test often is always a good idea.

I suggest putting your EF related classes in a separate project.