# Associating a model with a database table to perform INSERT using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the first table created on my own that I am trying to insert data.

Question: in my controller, I am not sure how to link the model with the actual database table to perform the `INSERT`.

Also in the line `uc.userId = userId;` I am getting the following error:

> *Invalid initializer member declarato*

I created a model for this table:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public bool isCertified { get; set; }
    public int certType { get; set; }
    public string identifier { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
   <td style="font-size:10px;">Habilitar Login com Cert. Digital:</td>
   <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isCertified)</td>
</tr>                                      
<div id="certDigitalBlock">
<tr>
    <td class="smallField">Tipo do Certificado:</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.certType, new SelectList(ViewBag.certType, "id","type"))</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Identificação:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.identifier, new { @class = "validate[required]" })      @Html.ValidationMessage("awnserVal", "*")</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Controller

```
using (tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities())
{
   var userID = from u in context.aspnet_Users where u.UserName == model.UserName select u.UserId;

   if (checkIsCertified == true)
   {
      UsersCertified uc = new UsersCertified {
                            uc.userId = userId;
                            uc.certTypeId = model.certType;
                            uc.keyNumber = model.identifier;
                        }

      context.SaveChanges()
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641371/entity-has-some-invalid-arguments-when-trying-to-perform-an-insert-with-ef

Thanks you all!

Comment: Problem solved:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641371/entity-has-some-invalid-arguments-when-trying-to-perform-an-insert-with-ef

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UsersCertified uc = new UsersCertified {
                            uc.userId = userId;
                            uc.certTypeId = model.certType;
                            uc.keyNumber = model.identifier;
                        }
```

Shouldn't be written under brackets? if you are using a constructor.

```
UsersCertified uc = new UsersCertified (
                            uc.userId = userId;
                            uc.certTypeId = model.certType;
                            uc.keyNumber = model.identifier;
                        )
```

Add this code:

```
context.UsersCertified .InsertOnSubmit(uc);
                context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Okay, now I fixed the controller but still have a second doubt. context.SaveChanges(); won´t create a new record. How can I perform a Insert?

Comment: I can't recall the exact syntax but it was something like context.addobject("");

Comment: Please, have a look my at comment in the post below. Thanks for your awnser.. mixel told me about the method, but still remain issues that I don´t understand

Comment: Instead of context.Set<UsersCertified>().Add(uc); try context.Add(uc);or try context.AddtoUser(uc);

Comment: But how context will know in which table we are inserting data?

Comment: I have edited my code and inserted some of my working project code.

Comment: there is no .InsertOnSubmit option in my context

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20376/discussion-between-codespread-and-guilherme-longo)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing

```
context.Set<UsersCertified>().Add(uc);
```

before

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

By the way you may want to read my answer about [Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549062/using-entity-framework/13550504#13550504) pattern. It can help you with understanding how to work with database and split your application by levels.

Comment: I get the following error: 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Thanks Mixel... uc is a class that is taking 3 parameter (Guid, int, string) ... my table is called sistema_UsersCertified so I have done the following:  UsersCertified uc = new UsersCertified(uID, model.certType, model.identifier);                            context.Set<sistema_UsersCertified>().Add(uc);  The compiler complains that the best overloaded method for that has some invalid arguments... how if they are of the same type?