# entity has some invalid arguments when trying to perform an INSERT with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I cannot find a way to perform a insert statement using EF.

Many error have emerged.

The code is all here and the problem is with the controller: I have alread tried:

```
context.sistema_UsersCertified.Add(uc);
context.Set<sistema_UsersCertified>().Add(uc);
```

It says that sistema_UsersCertified has some invalid argumments

why?

**This is my dbcontext:**

```
public partial class tgpwebgedEntities : DbContext
{
    public tgpwebgedEntities()
        : base("name=tgpwebgedEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<sistema_UsersCertified> sistema_UsersCertified { get; set; }

}
```

This table has 4 collumns: id(int), userID(Guid), certTypeID(int), keyNumber(string)

**so I have created a Model based in that table:**

```
   public class UsersCertified
{
    public Guid userId;
    public int certTypeId;
    public string keyNumber;

    public UsersCertified(Guid uId, int ctId, string kn) {
        userId = uId;
        certTypeId = ctId;
        keyNumber = kn;
    }
}
```

**and I have a viewthat send data to a controller:**

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Habilitar Login com Cert. Digital:</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isCertified)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="smallField">Tipo do Certificado:</td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.certType, new SelectList(ViewBag.certType, "id","type"))</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Identificação:</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.identifier, new { @class = "validate[required]" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("awnserVal", "*")</td>
                    </tr> 
                </table>
```

**and the last.. my controller:**

```
using (tgpwebgedEntities context = new tgpwebgedEntities()) {
                {
 var userID = from u in context.aspnet_Users where u.UserName == model.UserName select u.UserId;
                    Guid uID = userID.First();
UsersCertified uc = new UsersCertified(uID, model.certType, model.identifier);

//HERE I NEED SET MY TABLE WITH MY MODEL... BUT SO MANY ERROR

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I would use just context.sistema_UsersCertified.Add(uc); is it an exception or a build error - what is the exact text of the error?

Comment: What is `sistema_UsersCertified`? Maybe must be `DbSet<UsersCertified>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I think it may be that you are creating a model of type UsersCertified and then trying to save it as a database entity of type sistema_UsersCertified.

Try

```
sistema_UsersCertified dbEntity = new sistema_UsersCertified();
dbEntity.CertType = ...
context.sistema_UsersCertified.Add(dbEntity);
```